# Leetcode1002. Find Common Characters between Strings -Java

Tags: java, algorithm

The questions was:
Given an array A of strings made only from lowercase letters, return a list of all characters that show up in all strings within the list (including duplicates).  For example, if a character occurs 3 times in all strings but not 4 times, you need to include that character three times in the final answer.

You may return the answer in any order.

Example 1:

Input: ["bella","label","roller"]
Output: ["e","l","l"]

Example 2:

Input: ["cool","lock","cook"]
Output: ["c","o"]

Note:

1 <= A.length <= 100

1 <= A[i].length <= 100

A[i][j] is a lowercase letter

This is my code:

```java
class Solution {
    public List<String> commonChars(String[] A) {
        List<String> charArr = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 1; i<A.length ; i++){
            A[0].replaceAll("[^" + A[i] + "]", "");
        }
        for(int i=0; i<A[0].length(); i++){
            charArr.add(Character.toString(A[0].charAt(i)));
        }
        return charArr;

    }
}
```

The result I got

input:
["bella","label","roller"]

Output:
["b","e","l","l","a"]

Expected:
["e","l","l"]

Obviously the characters were not removed, can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: A[0].replaceAll("[^" + A[i] + "]", ""); you need to assign this to a string. like A[0] = A[0].replaceAll("[^" + A[i] + "]", ""); With this the algo still is not complete, but I think this is a good first point to move forward. So the reason you see all characters of bella in the output is because the first for loop is essentially doing nothing.

Comment: Using `replaceAll` simply cannot give a correct answer for number of duplicates of a particular letter. E.g. if input is `[aaa, a]`, you would return `[a, a, a]`, which is wrong, since second string only has one `a`. Re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: What you are doing is different from what the question wants you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about java, but here is the 1 liner in python

```
list(functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a&b, [Counter(c) for c in A]).elements())
```

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import functools

>>> A = ["bella","label","roller"]
>>> list(functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a&b, [Counter(c) for c in A]).elements())
['e', 'l', 'l']
>>> A =  ["cool","lock","cook"]
>>> list(functools.reduce(lambda a,b: a&b, [Counter(c) for c in A]).elements())
['c', 'o']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with Manaar's idea,
Thank you all for suggestions and comments!

```
**class Solution {
    public List<String> commonChars(String[] A) {
        List<String> charArr = new ArrayList<>();
        int[][] lowerCase = new int[26][A.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i< A.length ; i++){
            for(int j =0; j<A[i].length();j++)
            lowerCase[A[i].charAt(j)-'a'][i] ++;            
        }
        for(int i =0; i < 26 ;i++){
            int min = lowerCase[i][0];
            for(int j = 0 ; j< A.length ; j++){
                if(lowerCase[i][j]<min)
                    min = lowerCase[i][j];
            }
            while(min!=0){
                charArr.add(Character.toString((char)(i+'a')));
                min--;

            }
        }
        return charArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. The result on Leetcode: Runtime: 3 ms, faster than 87.52% of Java online submissions. Very good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo-code for how I would tackle this problem:

```
Place the letters from the first string of the array into a list
for each letter in the list{
    count the occurrences of the letter
    for each string in the array{
        count the occurrences of the letter
        if the letter occurs in the list more often than in the string{
            decrease occurrence of letter in list to match letter in string
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A bit changed version:

```
public List<String> commonChars01(String[] A) {
    int[][] lowerCase = new int[26][A.length];
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i< A.length ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < A[i].length(); j++) {
            lowerCase[A[i].charAt(j) -'a'][i] ++;
        }                        
    }        
  
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 
        // all the elements of the array should be equal
        long count = IntStream.of(lowerCase[i])
                .boxed().distinct().count();
        
        // [0, 0, 0] should fail, hence sum should be greater than or equal to 3.
        int sum = IntStream.of(lowerCase[i])
                .boxed().reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + b); 
                
        if ( sum >= 3 && count == 1) {
            int timesRepeated = lowerCase[i][0];
            while (timesRepeated != 0) {
                list.add(Character.toString((char)(i + 'a')));
                timesRepeated--;
            }
        }
    }        
    
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below out -

```
 public List<String> commonChars(String[] words) {

    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    int wordNums = words.length;
    int[][] charNums = new int[wordNums][26];
    for (int i = 0; i < wordNums; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j++) {
            charNums[i][words[i].charAt(j) - 'a'] +=1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        int count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (; j < wordNums; j++) {
            if(charNums[j][i] == 0 ){
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
            count = Math.min(count, charNums[j][i]);
        }
        for(int k = 0;k<count;k++){
            ans.add(String.valueOf((char) (i + 'a')));
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```